# Find the probability $P(X\ge a)$ where $X$ is the sum of $k$ random numbers from a set of positive integers $\{1,...,m\}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-variables

> $k$ numbers are being added, where each number can be randomly chosen from a set of positive integers $\{1,2,...,m\}$. Let their sum be $X$. Find the probability $P(X\ge a)$.

My attempt: I wrote an equation $$x_1+x_2+\dots +x_k=X$$
Since $X \in [k, mk]$, I tried to combine number of solutions of equations like above for $X \in [a, mk]$ and divide to the combined number of solutions for $X \in [k, mk]$ (all possible combinations of sums). To count this I used the formula for combinations with repetitions: $$\cfrac{(n+r-1)!}{r!(n-1)!}$$

However, this formula does not make any constraints on each $x_i$ to be from the set $\{1,2,...,m\}$. So this should be the wrong solution.

Comment: When you say randomly chosen, you mean uniformly?

Comment: @Phicar Yes. Choosing any with the same probability

Answer (score 1):

So now you have to exclude the solutions that are not allowed. Call $$ A_{r,i} = 
\{(x_1,x_2,\cdots ,x_k)\in [m]^k:x_i>m \text{ and }\sum x_i=r \},$$
For a fixed $r,$ you want $$A_r=\left |\text{All solutions}\setminus \bigcup _{i=1}^kA_{r,i}\right |,$$ Notice that all solutions are given by $\binom{r-1}{k-1}$ and that $$|A_{r,i}|=\binom{r-m-1}{k-1}$$ cause you are just taking away the $m$ from the $x_i'$th variable. 
Analogously, $$\left|A_{r,i}\cap A_{r,j}\right |=\binom{r-2\cdot m-1}{k-1}$$ because now you have to take out the $m$ from the $i-$th and the $j-th$ coordinate. 
Using inclusion exclusion you get that $$A_r=\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^{i}\color{blue}{\binom{k}{i}}\binom{r-i\cdot m-1}{k-1}.$$
You can think that the $\color{blue}{blue}$ binomial represents choosing the variables that will overlap $m$ so the answer will be
$$P(X\geq a)=\frac{1}{m^k}\sum _{r=a}^{m\cdot k}\sum_{i=0}^k(-1)^{i}\color{blue}{\binom{k}{i}}\binom{r-i\cdot m-1}{k-1}$$